# any alternative to mysql left join copy table_B content in table_A without duplicates

Tags: mariadb, left-join, mariadb-10.6

Given the two tables:

```
create table table_A (col1 int, col2 int);

insert into table_A values(10,10);
insert into table_A values(15,15);
insert into table_A values(35,35);
insert into table_A values(45,45);

create table table_B (col1 int, col2 int);

insert into table_B values(10,10);
insert into table_B values(2000,2000);
insert into table_B values(35,35);
insert into table_B values(6000,6000);
```

I want to copy contents of each row from table_B to table_A except if the lines are duplicated.
Correct output after applying a LEFT JOIN is:

```
select * from table_A;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|   10 |   10 |
|   15 |   15 |
|   35 |   35 |
|   45 |   45 |
| 2000 | 2000 |
| 6000 | 6000 |
+------+------+

select * from table_B;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|   10 |   10 |
| 2000 | 2000 |
|   35 |   35 |
| 6000 | 6000 |
+------+------+
```

The query I used is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test_leftjoin.table_A (
    SELECT DISTINCT test_leftjoin.table_B.*
    from test_leftjoin.table_B
    LEFT JOIN test_leftjoin.table_A
        ON (
            test_leftjoin.table_B.col1 = test_leftjoin.table_A.col1 and
            test_leftjoin.table_B.col2 = test_leftjoin.table_A.col2
        ) 
    WHERE (
        test_leftjoin.table_A.col1 IS NULL AND
        test_leftjoin.table_A.col2 IS NULL
    )
);
```

This is simple because there are only two columns in the tables, but if I have to write the same query for tables with 20-30 columns it gets very complicated and big.

Are there alternatives to using the JOIN here or simplifying the ON and WHERE matches to include all columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the rows are duplicated, does it matter if they're copied?

Comment: Table_A doesn't have duplicated rows on it's own. I'm trying to avoid exactly this.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? [EXCEPT clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html) was added in 8.0.31

Comment: I was using mariaDB version 10.6.11 but I will take a look thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using MariaDB 10.6.11 you can use the [EXCEPT clause](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/except/), which was added in 10.3:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_A
SELECT * FROM table_B EXCEPT ALL SELECT * FROM table_A;
```

For your sample data, `SELECT * FROM table_A;` returns:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 |
| 15 | 15 |
| 35 | 35 |
| 45 | 45 |
| 2000 | 2000 |
| 6000 | 6000 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zoA1pu_3).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the version which doesn't support EXCEPT clause, I suppose using a correlated subquery instead of JOIN can make the coding more concise:

```
    insert table_a  
        select distinct * from table_b b 
        where not exists (select 1 from table_a a 
                        where b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2=a.col2)  ;
```

Note: Without the `distinct` keyword , duplicate inserts can happen if table b has duplicate rows.